# posts pagination in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

i want to show 4 posts in page and after 4 posts it will show next button to read next posts.

```
        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>


<?php
            global $post;
            $myposts = get_posts('numberposts=4&order=ASC&category=3');
            foreach($myposts as $post) :
            setup_postdata($post);

            ?>
```

here is content with html

```
        <?php endforeach; ?>


        <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? What have you tried? Would this not be better solved using an existing plugin? (I'm sure there is one in the plugin base)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add `paged` parameter to your query_posts:

```
$myposts = get_posts('numberposts=4&order=ASC&category=3&paged' . get_query_var('paged'));
```

And add [post_nav_link()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Next_and_Previous_Links) to display `next` and `prev` link.

```
<?php posts_nav_link(); ?>
```

Cheers, oh, btw, you can post specific wordpress question at wordpress.stackexchange.com.